# same queries using 'regexp' gives different result in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, unicode, rlike

Basically, what I want, is to understand why

`select 'aa' regexp '[h]'` returns 0 and

`select 'აა' regexp '[ჰ]'` returns 1 ?

check [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/29473)

Comment: Just an assumption. Without character class it's working fine. Maybe because in this case the byte-sequence is matched. First bytes of [ა](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10d0/index.htm) and [ჰ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10f0/index.htm) are identical: `E183` (hex). So those in the class would match. Also tried using utf8_bin without success. Weird :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think MqSQL regex does not support utf-8 yet. See [bug 30241](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30241)  and [12.5.2 Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html).

> Warning
>
> The REGEXP and RLIKE operators work in **byte-wise fashion, so they are not multibyte safe** and may produce unexpected results with multibyte character sets. In addition, these operators compare characters by their byte values and accented characters may not compare as equal even if a given collation treats them as equal.

You could match the byte sequence without character class: `SELECT 'აა' REGEXP 'ჰ'` returns `0`.